# Java Concurrent Multimap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hash-map

I've implemented a concurrent multimap that support concurrent put and remove but I'm unsure of its correctness. I would appreciate your feedback.

```
public class ConcurrentMultiMap<K, V> {
    private static ConcurrentHashMap emptySet = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    private ConcurrentHashMap<K, ConcurrentHashMap<V, Object>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    // return true if the method increased the size of the multimap or false if the multimap already contained the key-value pair
    public boolean put(K k, V v) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(k);
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(v);
        boolean tryAgain;
        boolean success = true;
        do {
            ConcurrentHashMap<V, Object> oldSet = map.get(k);
            if (oldSet == null) {
                tryAgain = map.putIfAbsent(k, new ConcurrentHashMap<>(Collections.singeltonMap(v, 1))) != null;
            } else {
                success = oldSet.putIfAbsent(v, 1) == null; //I do not allow multiple equal values for the same key
                if (success) {
                    // if the put was a success we check that the key was not removed from the map by a concurrent remove operation.
                    ConcurrentHashMap<V, Object> currentSet = map.get(k);
                    tryAgain = currentSet == null || !currentSet.contains(v);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } while(tryAgain);
            return success;
    }

    // returns true if the multimap changed
    public boolean remove(K k, V v) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(k);
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(v);
        ConcurrentHashMap<V, Object> oldSet = map.get(k);
        if (oldSet == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (oldSet.remove(v) != null) {
            if (oldSet.size() == 0) {
                map.remove(k, emptySet);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not extending from any other collection classes/interfaces; do you provide functionality for *getting* things from the multimap?

Comment: I'm implementing guava multimap. I didn't include the full implementation of the class in the code above to keep the focus on the put/remove methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "concurrent"?

Comment: @SolomonUcko concurrent means that the methods will be called from multiple threads of execution. In the implementation above I'm using concurrent hash map, which is a class from the java.util package which guarantees a form of consistency when used from several threads, moreover it does so without locking the entire map and thus it is considered efficient. You can read more about it here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ and here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: That's what I thought, but can you take a look at my answer and explain why it's wrong if it's wrong?

Comment: Your code has many mistakes and won't even compile. `v` or `value`?  `while(tryAgain)` is in an impossible place.

Comment: @toto2 it was a typo I've edited the post and replaced value by v. Regarding the while(tryAgain), this is standard do while syntax.

Comment: Not sure why you put it after the remove again, but otherwise it looks ok

Comment: @SolomonUcko I have added a comment to your answer

Comment: @eckes I'm not sure which part bothers you. Could you please indicate the code section that you are uncertain about.

Comment: @EladTolochinsky the `if (success)` part.

Comment: @Elad No it's not standard while-syntax:  your ` while(tryAgain)` closes the `if (oldSet == null)` code block, not `do`.

Answer (score -2):

You should have `HashMap<K, Set<V>>`, not `ConcurrentHashMap<K, ConcurrentHashMap<V, Object>>`.

Comment: Why did someone
 down vote? Is the answer too short? Is it incorrect? If it is incorrect, please explain why.

Comment: I think it's because you didn't explain, _why_ he should use HashMap. And you ask what he means by 'concurrent', which is imo necessary to understand beforehand, to be able to give a proper answer.

Comment: @slowy, I added a comment to the question, I'll edit later.

Comment: My implementation relies heavily on the concurrency guarantees given by ConcurrentHashMap. By replacing it with HashMap not only that my code will not support concurrent put and remove it will not even support modifications from different threads done in a sequential manner due to lack of memory barriers.

Comment: @EladTolochinsky Oh, oops. It looked like you were defining `ConcurrentHashMap`, not `ConcurrentMultiMap`. Should I delete this answer?